# How to prove that this function of two variables is a surjection?

Tags: functions, proof-writing

Let:

$A=\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m, \dots\}$

$B=\{b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n,\dots\}$

Define $f:A\times B \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^+$ as:

$(a_m,b_n) \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(m+n-2)(m+n-1)+n$

How do I show that $f$ is surjective?

I know I need to show that for any given positive integer,$p$, there exists two positive integers, $m$ and $n$ such that $\frac{1}{2}(m+n-2)(m+n-1)+n=p$.

If $f$ were a function of 1 variable only, then this would be straight forward as I can try to find its inverse by reversing the operations defined in $f$.

However, I am not so sure what to do in the case of two variables. Do I have to show that if I assume that if $m$ or $n$ are some fixed positive integer, then there is a solution for $p$?

Answer (score 1):

Note: OP's suggested approach will not work; you will need to vary both $m,n$ to find a particular $p$.

Consider the new variable $u=m+n-1$.  Now because $m,n$ are each in $\mathbb{N}$, it turns out that $u,n$ must satisfy $1\le n\le u$.  This will be important later.

You want $\frac{u^2-u}{2}+n=p$.  First, you need to prove that by varying $u$ you can find a value for $u$ such that $$\frac{u^2-u}{2}<p\le \frac{(u+1)^2-(u+1)}{2}$$

Second, you set $n=p-\frac{u^2-u}{2}$, and need to prove that $n$ satisfies $1\le n\le u$.

Comment: I haven't tried to prove the the inequalities you described yet. Could you elaborate further how the two inequalities helps to establish that $f$ is surjective?

Answer (score 0):

A hint:

The map $f$ implements a well known proof of the countability of the rationals.